# How to call a Firestore field which contains another field name

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a "products" collection in Firestore and I am getting a document from it using below method

```
const docRef = doc(db, "products", id);
const [product, setProduct] = useState({});


const getProduct = async () => {
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);

      if (docSnap.exists()) {
        setProduct(docSnap.data());
      } else {
        console.log("no product!");
      }
    };
```

There is an array field called types and I am uploading images for each type. So that img url field looked like this: (type+ 'url')

I can call the product name by `product.name` and type by `product.type`. But I don't know how to call the type img url field like `product.(type+ ‘ Url’)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use bracket notation for dynamic property access:

```js
product[`${product.type} URL`];

// If product.type is "a", then this does:
product["a URL"]
```

[MDN Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation)